# Getting access token from refresh token using async task

Tags: android, asynchronous, okhttp

I an trying to retrieve access token from refresh token by running an async task in background. I am using okHttp interceptor and whenever i get 401 or 500 I initiate asynctask for getting access token. The problem I am facing is that, before the access token obtained from async task in saved in shared preferences the code flow moves forward and the old access token again gets set resulting in same 401/500 errors. How to make sure that interceptor retires only after fresh token has been saved.

Anyone please provide suggestion as I need an answer at the earliest.

Thanks,

Comment: Move your code to `onPostExecute()` that needs to be executed after the new token is obtained.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In onPostExecute() i am using a callback and passing response as its parameter. Like: mCallBack.onTokenResponse(Response resp, Exception ex) and I am saving the token where I am implementing this callback.